# How do I collapse a menu on a one-page layout?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have taken over a project from another developer that I am trying to clean up and improve. The company who owns the site wanted a one-page layout, so I began building that, but I am having trouble with the responsive navbar, which comes with a dropdown menu. My problem is that when I press one of the links in the dropdown section, it will take me to the correct section of the page, but if I want to go to one of the other links afterwards I have to refresh the page, because the dropdown menu will not appear when I hover over the list item.

I know it sounds confusing, but let me show you the test page I am making, and maybe it will be more clear (I am sorry that it is not in english)
http://www.handig.dk/test/index.html

When you are on the page, hover over the item called "Menukort". You notice that the dropdown menu appears right? Try clicking on one of the links. Once you have done that, try hovering over "Menukort" again. Do you notice that the dropdown menu no longer appears?
Also if you CLICK on "Menukort", you are brought back to the top of the page, which I do not want either.

Do you have any suggestions of how to fix this problem?

Here is the code for the navbar.

The HTML

```
    <section class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container" id="myHeader">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="#">Forside</a></li>
        <li><a href="#om_os">Om os</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Menukort</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li><a href="#frokost">Frokost</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aften">Aften</a></li>
            <li><a href="#drikke">Drikkevarer</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://book.dinnerbooking.com/dk/da-DK/book/table/pax/1620/3">Bordbestilling</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#ud_af_huset">Mad ud af huset</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li><a href="#take_away">Take Away</a></li>
            <li><a href="#festbuffet">Festbuffet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#brunch">Brunch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reception">Receptionsmad</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#selskaber">Selskaber</a></li>
        <li><a href="#hotellet">Hotellet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#find">Find os</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

The CSS

```
    .nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  color: #84a0a8;
}
nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: '';
}
nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
nav ul li:hover .nav-dropdown {
    display: block;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.sticky + .nav-container {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

/* Mobile navigation */
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  height: 35px;/* ???? */
  /*width: 25px;*/
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }

  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
 #nav-toggle{
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 35px 16px;
    display:table;
    margin:-35px auto 0;
  }
#nav-toggle span{margin:auto;left:0;right:0;}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

The JavaScript (The slideUp function does not work either for some reason. I cannot get the menu to close after I click on a link in the mobile menu)

```
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
  $(function() { // DOM ready
    // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      // Close one dropdown when selecting another
      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    // Hamburger to X toggle
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    $('.nav-dropdown li a').on("click", function(){
    $('#nav-toggle').slideUp();
});
  }); // end DOM ready
})(jQuery); // end jQuery
```

Comment: I have to imagine that the click handler for the entire document (`html`) is the problem. I'd be converting the dropdown part of this to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
});
```

When you put .hide make that the css hide the element and you cant see it replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I added a hover function to toggle the menu just as the click is doing. Right now, the css provides that rule, but gets overwritten by the JQuery after it toggles it closed. Use javascript:void(0) instead of # to avoid anchoring to the top of the page.

Pen:
https://codepen.io/richiegarcia/pen/oNxmXGK

```
    (function($) { // Begin jQuery
      $(function() { // DOM ready
        //Hover shows submenu
        $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').hover(function(e) {
          $(this).children('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
          // Close one dropdown when selecting another
        });
        
        // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
        $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
          $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
          // Close one dropdown when selecting another
          $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
          e.stopPropagation();
        });
        // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
        $('html').click(function() {
          $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
        });
        // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
        $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
          $('nav ul').slideToggle();
        });
        // Hamburger to X toggle
        $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
          this.classList.toggle('active');
        });
        $('.nav-dropdown li a').on("click", function(){
        $('#nav-toggle').slideUp();
    });
      }); // end DOM ready
    })(jQuery); // end jQuery
```